# Required rsyslog fields not getting printed in the logs

Tags: logging, syslog, rsyslog

I have a query in relation to required rsyslog fields not getting displayed in the log messages.

**Environment details –** There are multiple microservices which are sending logs to another application named Log Transformer. Log transformer application is enriching fields present in those log messages and then sending all the logs to rsyslog server. For the reference that version of rsyslog is 8.2004.0

**Requirement –** logs, getting dumped in rsyslog server at the configured file, should have following fields:

```
Priority
Hostname
Program
TAG
Message
facility_code
facility
Severity
severity_code
Timestamp
```

**Following is the rsyslog configuration:**

```
$MaxMessageSize 32768

# Remote
module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="514")
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514")

$template logstreamingfmt,"<%PRI%>%TIMESTAMP% %HOSTNAME% %app-name% %procid% %syslogfacility% %syslogfacility-text% %syslogpriority% %syslogpriority-text% %syslogseverity% %syslogseverity-text% %syslogtag%%msg%\n"

*.* -/var/log/log-transformer.log
```

**Following are the few sample messages getting printed in the log file where not all fields are present in the logs:**

```
2023-03-02T12:27:19.308+00:00 - microservice1-7dcd9b4c77-s6xwh INFO  [com.test.microserviceTest] (Thread-89 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) Processing command get all fields
```

**Could someone please suggest what could go wrong here.**

Is it that given template in rsyslog configuration file is incorrect.

```
$template logstreamingfmt,"<%PRI%>%TIMESTAMP% %HOSTNAME% %app-name% %procid% %syslogfacility% %syslogfacility-text% %syslogpriority% %syslogpriority-text% %syslogseverity% %syslogseverity-text% %syslogtag%%msg%"
```

How to check in rsyslog server what original message is being consumed from upstream system because that way, I will be able to figure out if expected fields in logs are present in original message or not.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are not applying the template when logging to `/var/log/log-transformer.log`.

To apply the template, modify the config like the following:

```
*.* -/var/log/log-transformer.log;logstreamingfmt
```

Alternatively, you can use the RainerScript syntax, which *(in most cases)* can make configs easier to read and write. Here's the equivalent of your config in RainerScript:

```
template(
    name="logstreamingfmt"
    type="string"
    string="<%PRI%>%TIMESTAMP% %HOSTNAME% %app-name% %procid% %syslogfacility% %syslogfacility-text% %syslogpriority% %syslogpriority-text% %syslogseverity% %syslogseverity-text% %syslogtag%%msg%\n"
)

action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/log-transformer.log" template="logstreamingfmt")
```

Comment: thanks for great inputs. It has worked for me.